# how to find xml element by attribute value using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xliff

Attempting to parse an `XML` with namespaces and attributes. I wish to retrieve an element by a given attribute (`id`).

Documentation specifies but

> [@attrib] Selects all elements that have the given attribute.
>
> [@attrib='value'] Selects all elements for which the given attribute has the given value. The value cannot contain quotes.

neither solutions below returns an element when given an attribute name & value or when given an attribute name only

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse("es.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

print root.findall('file/body/trans-unit', root.nsmap)


# Unable to fetch all with attribute == id
print root.findall('file/body/trans-unit[@id]', root.nsmap)

# Unable to fetch element with id = 111
print root.find('file/body/trans-unit[@id="111"]', root.nsmap)
```

#### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<file original="PDDDD" source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" target-language="es">
<header>
<tool tool-id="com.apple.dt.xcode" tool-name="Xcode" tool-version="10.1" build-num="10B61"/>
</header>
<body>
<trans-unit id="111">
<source>Welcome!</source>
<target>Welcome!</target>
<note>Class = "UILabel"; text = "Welcome!"; ObjectID = "7oz-Od-KDt";</note>
</trans-unit>
</body>
</file>
</xliff>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it with the `{None: "urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2"}` namespace of `root.nsmap`...

However, if you redefine a namespace map like

```
ns = {"n": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2"}
```

then this works

```
root.find('.//n:trans-unit[@id="111"]', ns)
```